# Hide menu and do an absolute position of every item of page

Tags: html, css

I'm new in css and I working with pure css menu and I want to hide items of menu when checkbox is checked. I try it but it only work in mobile media size:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin:0px;
}

#main-slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 528px;
    /* border-radius: 0% 0% 50% 50% / 0% 0% 20% 20%; */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 25%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 25%;
    position: relative;
}

/* menu */

.main .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.main .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.main .menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.main .menu-icon .nav-icon:before,
.main .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.main .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.main .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.main .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.main .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.main .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: transparent;
}

.main .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top:0;
}

.main .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top:0;
}



@media (min-width: 48em) {
  
  .main li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .main .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<main> 
          <div class="main">
          <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
            <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#dont">Test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#forget">Test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#forget">Test3</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
            <section>
                <div class="slider-wrapper">
                  <img id="main-slider" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1365x528?text=Slider">
                  
                </div>
              </section>
              </main>
```

So, the objective of this is:

- A menu that works in mobile and desktop, but it will always display as hamburger menu(desktop and mobile)
- Stay at the top right of page always, including scroll

How can I achieve that? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you a hidden menu on css. Is that how it should be? If you need to improve something, please report it.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin:0px;
}

#main-slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 528px;
    /* border-radius: 0% 0% 50% 50% / 0% 0% 20% 20%; */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 25%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 25%;
    position: relative;
}

/* menu */

.main .menu {
  clear: both;
  /*max-height: 0;*/
  display: none;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.main .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.main .menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.main .menu-icon .nav-icon:before,
.main .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.main .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.main .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.main .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.main .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  display: block;
}

.main .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: transparent;
}

.main .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top:0;
}

.main .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top:0;
}



@media (min-width: 48em) {
  
  .main li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .main .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<main> 
          <div class="main">
          <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
            <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#dont">Test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#forget">Test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#forget">Test3</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
            <section>
                <div class="slider-wrapper">
                  <img id="main-slider" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1365x528?text=Slider">
                  
                </div>
              </section>
              </main>
```

Comment: Awesome, now menu is hidden, but how can I open it vertically, I mean when it open display it vertically taking part of slider

Comment: At the end of the day I want to cover all my web page vertically not just slider

Comment: what do you mean by "display it vertically"? please show a screenshot, or some example, so that I have an idea, and I will help you.

Comment: But for now, this is how your menu looks. Mobile only on the left.

Comment: Now I'm not quite clear what exactly you want. Can you give a specific explanation?

Comment: I think I will do another question with that specific requirements because you answer this question correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220057/discussion-between-sergey-kuznetsov-and-jesus).

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add `'position : fixed' , 'top : 1rem' , 'right: 1rem'` to whatever your div that contains the hamburger,if you only want to above stated functionalities.

and a advise: use javascrip dom for css menus rather than checkbox.declare a function that controls `display: block` and `display:none` and bind it to your body like this:

```
<body onreload=func() onscroll=func()>
...
</body>
```